# AngularJS: как удалить из таблицы элемент

Tags: angularjs

Из б.д. вывожу список мобильных устройств.

```
<tbody ng-app="testApp" ng-controller='TestCntr'>
       <tr ng-repeat='dev in device'>
         <td>
             <a href="site.ru/device/">{{dev.name}}</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            Продан: {{dev.date}}      
         </td>
         <td>
             <a title="Delete" ng-click="archive(dev.id)">×</a>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

По нажатию на ссылку "Delete", сделал обработчик удаления устройства из б.д. :

```
$scope.archive = function(id) {
    if (confirm("Вы уверенны, что хотите удалить устройство?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "http://site.com/device/delete/",
                    data: {'id' : id
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Как при успешной обработке команды, удалить `<tr>` с описанием из самой таблицы?

Answer (score 1):

Тут как с ложками - нет никакой таблицы.
Просто удалите элемент из массива `$scope.device`

```
let index = $scope.device.find(dev => dev.id === id);
if (index !== -1) $scope.device.splice(index, 1);
```

Чтобы было проще искать нужный элемент лучше передавать в обработчик клика не `dev.id`, а `dev`

---

*Не поддавайтесь соблазну использовать индекс для адресации элементов в массиве - за время выполнения аякс запроса индексы элементов могут измениться.*

---

Так как вы пользуетесь нестандартным методом для аякс запросов(не $http сервис) вам также необходимо уведомить angular о том, что вы меняли $scope:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Но лучше таки посмотреть в сторону $http

Comment: Проблема в том, что $http вызывает ошибку или напросто не передаёт post, ajax такой ситуации не вызывает

Comment: В этой ошибке вам помогут разобраться если вы оформите подробности как новый вопрос